# Split one column into two based on numbers and letters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basically, I am trying to remove all the numbers at the end of rows and store them in another column.

So I initially have something like this at the start:

```
Original List
Dr Pepper;1234
Pepsi 90s Drink001
Coca Cola
Red Bull R3 Drink
Mountain Dew;11
Gatorade
Fanta
Crush Soda456
```

I then want to split it so I get one list solely for the soft drink names and then one list solely for numbers at the end. So something like this:

```
Soft Drinks
Dr Pepper
Pepsi 90s Drink
Coca Cola
Red Bull R3 Drink
Mountain Dew
Gatorade
Fanta
Crush Soda
```

And then any numbers that appear at the list like:

```
Numbers
1234
1


11


456
```

I know you can use `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A&"","[a-zA-Z\s]+"))` but then it wouldnt get `Red Bull R3 Drink` for example and instead get `Red Bull R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(split(regexreplace(A2:A9, "(;?)(\d+)$","/$2"), "/"))
```

[image]

---

### Explanation

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/t1an8u/1) for an explanation of the regex pattern.

---

Comment: Thanks mate! Just a couple of questions. What does the `"/$2"` do in the `regexreplace`? Also, what does the `"/` do at the end?

Comment: In formula you have 2 capturing groups. First one is `(;?)` and second one is `(\d+)` So, `"$2"` says "replace both of this `(;?)(\d+)` with only the second group" We add and use the `/` for SPLIT. You can change it to something else . Try this to understand better: `=ArrayFormula(split(regexreplace(A2:A9, "(;?)(\d+)$","@$2"), "@"))`

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks for juming in, @Swen.

Comment: He tries to understand and learn. This is very good. Not like others who take answer, disappear and not even thank you.

Comment: Accepted answer. Thanks